# React state is undefined after checking for undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

so I've been working on this React app.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const serverLocation = require("../config/keys.js").server;

var data = [];

export default class StanjeNaCestah extends React.Component {
    state = {
        datag: [],
        finished: false
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`${serverLocation}/api/content/road-conditions`).then(res => {
            this.setState(
                {
                    datag: res.data
                },
                function() {
                    console.log("Datag updated");
                    console.log(this.state);
                    this.setState(
                        {
                            finished: true
                        },
                        () => {
                            console.log("Finished true");
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
            for (var key in this.state) {
                data.push(this.state[key]);
            }
        });
    }

    componentWillUpdate() {
        console.log("WillUpdating");
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    render() {
        console.log("Render called");
        console.log(this.state.datag.items);
        //const itemz = this.state.datag.items.map((item, key) => <h3>{item}</h3>);
        let numbers;
        //numbers = this.state.datag.items;
        if (this.state.datag.items) {
            numbers = this.state.datag.items.forEach(item => {
                console.log("Iterating through for item " + item.title);
                return <div>{item.title}</div>;
            });
        }
        console.log("Logging numbers");
        console.log(numbers);
        return <ul>{numbers}</ul>;
        /*return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="col-xs-8">
                    <h1>{this.state.datag.title}</h1>
                    {itemz}
                </div>
            </div>
        );*/
    }
}
```

The problem is the code in the render. As you can see, I am checking for this.state.datag.items being undefined. The console.log that I'm calling in the 2nd line of the function is returning the valid value. But later, where I log the numbers it returns undefined. The part in the forEach logs a valid value...
I've run out of ideas what could be wrong here, please. Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that `Array.prototype.forEach` doesn't return a value. I suspect, given the code you've written, you're looking for `Array.prototype.map` instead.

Per the [MDN documentation for `Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> Return value
>
> `undefined`

```js
            numbers = this.state.datag.items.map(item => {
                console.log("Iterating through for item " + item.title);
                return <div>{item.title}</div>;
            });
```

Comment: There's no other way of saying this, I love you. Thank you so much :)